# How to show that $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\cot^2(2x)\over 2+\tan^6x+\cot^6x} dx={\pi\over 6^3}?$

Tags: calculus

How to show that

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\cot^2(2x)\over 2+\tan^6x+\cot^6x}\mathrm dx={\pi\over 6^3}?\tag1$$

This seem very difficult to break down. Any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not. Use symmetry to reduce the problem to an integral over $(0,\pi/2)$, then set $x=\arctan t$. 
The problem boils down to computing the integral of a rational function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, that is straightforward through the residue theorem. If you are able to compute
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{t^4(t^2-1)^2}{(t^6+1)^2(t^2+1)}\,dt $$
you are able to solve the given problem, too.

Comment: i really admire your patience... (+1)

Comment: @TonyJaa: it is not the place or the time to lose your temper, guys. Please try to stay calm and discuss politely.